Macbook Pro 2011 - OSX 10.11.6 - boot freeze on last step (black screen)
I have Macbook Pro 17, Early 2011, installed OSX 10.11.6 (El Capitan).
I have partly failed dedicated GPU, which I fixed 5 years ago by using SW method
to disable dGPU, and always use Intel integrated GPU. Fixed sleep function and keyboard backlight associated problems.
So, everything was working OK for years, and I didn't install anything new on OSX at least 6 months.
Recently I noticed that sleep function (closing laptop lid) wasn't working.
To try to fix the problem I rebooted laptop, but after few screen of typical
verbose console text bootup log info, it just stuck on black screen.

Sandbox: apsd(237) deny(1) system-fsctl 682f

When booted in safe mode, it shows the same error.
I tried bootup by disconnecting battery (which was newly replaced few month back),
removing and switching RAM memory slots, which eliminated RAM problem unless both memory RAMs are having some problems.
Disk utility scan of SSD drive showed no errors (in recovery mode), and I also used removed SSD,
connected as external drive on another Mac, used DriveDx (one of better diagnostic programs) to scanned it and it found no problems or errors on it.
I have done reset of PVRAM and SMC, and Recovery mode shows that GUI and GPU works OK.
I have gone over /var/system.log but I didn't find any errors.
I don't have proper backup (Time Machine) so I need to fix the problem, or reinstall the OSX without losing data.
Second problem is that this older OSX 10.11 in recovery mode doesn't have reinstall, only install option.
And all documentation on the internet only shows how to create bootable USB to install OSX, but I'm not sure that it will keep my data, once it is installed.
Does anyone knows what error "apsd(237) deny(1) system-fsctl 682f" could be?
